# What are the quarantine requirements for entering Germany after June 15

Tags: germany, covid-19

Related to [When do German borders reopen for EU members exactly?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/157654/when-do-german-borders-reopen-for-eu-members-exactly) but not this questions is specific to quarantine requirements.

What are the quarantine requirements for a German citizen entering Germany from outside the EU?

At the moment there appears to be a 14-day quarantine requirement but that appears to be up to the states. https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/einreiseundaufenthalt/coronavirus

Does this change with the June 15 updates ?

Comment: Starting on the 16th of June, some restrictions on travel **within the Schengen Area** are being lifted. Nothing has yet changed for travel from **outside the Schengen Area**. See [suggestions from the European Commission](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/157643/95267) made yesterday on this topic.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure why this was down-voted, I finally got the answer figured out, but it took a non-trivial amount of research and work, so I'm posting here in case someone else wants to know this.

Here is the answer

- The quarantine rules in Germany are jurisdiction of the states, not the federal government
- For Bavaria the latest and greatest are here  https://www.verkuendung-bayern.de/baymbl/2020-335/ and it has indeed been updated on June 15, 2020
- Bavaria requires 14-day quarantine for anyone that arrives from a "risk area"
- The determination of risk area is done by the Robert Koch Institut and updated frequently. https://www.rki.de/DE/Content/InfAZ/N/Neuartiges_Coronavirus/Risikogebiete_neu.html
- The Robert Koch Institut assesses each US state individually, as of today about half of the US states are risk areas and the other ones are not.

So the overall answer is **"depends on what US state you are coming from AND which German state you are going to"**. In my case, Massachusetts to Bavaria, I do NOT need to quarantine. That has been confirmed by the local health office (Gesundheitsamt) in my target town. No quarantine needed but I'm supposed to register with them on arrival.

Comment: I would recommend to print out this list on your day of arrival in Germany for your documementation.